# Can I view my files sorted by date?

Tags: nautilus, sort

Can I view  my files sorted by date?

I want to see my files sorted by date,  I mean the first one the newest. I didn't find this option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

If you are in list view in Nautilus, click over the top of the column "Date Modified". This will sort your files by date (newest to oldest). If you click twice, it will sort them from oldest to newest.

[image]

For a solution that affects all directories choose *Edit -> Preferences* and set your preferred layout:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Nautilus press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. Now you'll see a list view.

In a terminal, type `ls -t` or `ls -tr` to reverse the order.

You can sort by 'time' in both of these ways.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04:

1. Right-click on the white/gray background of the file manager
2. Move mouse over "Arrange Items"
3. Click "By Modification Date"