# Organize desktop by name in Nemo

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, nemo, file-sorting

I'm using Nemo as my file manager and when I press the right mouse button the only option to sort my Desktop is by Name.

[image: right click Desktop menu]

Is it possible to sort by other values, like Date Modified?

Comment: This has been mentioned in other places across the internet, and so far I haven't seen a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not possible.

[Nemo is a fork of nautilus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager))

When I right click on my desktop, I can't see a sort by anything else either:

[image: Nautilus right click menu]

Have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38404/can-i-view-my-files-sorted-by-date).